# marshmallow-jsonapi: How to reuse schema but change the `type_`?

Tags: python, json-api, marshmallow

I have many endpoints but they use the same jsonapi schema.

```
POST /foods
{
    "data": {
        "type": "food",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "abc",
            "item": "food"
        }
    }
}
```

```
POST /chats
{
    "data": {
        "type": "food",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "bcd",
            "item": "chat"
        }
    }
}
```

```
POST /animals
{
    "data": {
        "type": "food",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "poi",
            "item": "animals"
        }
    }
}
```

My schema is:

```
import marshmallow_jsonapi as jsonapi
ItemSchema(jsonapi.Schema):
    id = jsonapi.fields.UUID(dumps_only=True)
    name = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)
    item = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)

    class Meta:
        type_ = "items"
        strict = True
```

Following the jsonapi standard, the `type` will need to match each endpoint (`foods`, `chats`, `animals`).

```
import marshmallow_jsonapi as jsonapi
FoodSchema(jsonapi.Schema):
    id = jsonapi.fields.UUID(dumps_only=True)
    name = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)
    item = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)

    class Meta:
        type_ = "foods"
        strict = True
```

```
import marshmallow_jsonapi as jsonapi
ChatSchema(jsonapi.Schema):
    id = jsonapi.fields.UUID(dumps_only=True)
    name = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)
    item = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)

    class Meta:
        type_ = "chats"
        strict = True
```

```
import marshmallow_jsonapi as jsonapi
AnimalSchema(jsonapi.Schema):
    id = jsonapi.fields.UUID(dumps_only=True)
    name = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)
    item = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)

    class Meta:
        type_ = "animals"
        strict = True
```

What is a way to reduce redundant code to not have a bunch of copies of the `ItemSchema` with only the `type` changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the Base class** (BaseClass.py)

```
from marshmallow_jsonapi import fields, Schema
    
class Base(Schema):
    id = jsonapi.fields.UUID(dumps_only=True)
    name = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)
    item = jsonapi.fields.String(required=True)
```

**You can import the Base class in other schemas**

```
from BaseClass import Base

FoodSchema(Base):
    # add other fields if required

class Meta:
    type_ = "foods"
    strict = True
```

> Other Schema you need with same fields

```
from Base import Base

ChatSchema(Base):
    # add other fields if required
    
class Meta:
    type_ = "chats"
    strict = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a year too late. But you can extend from a `BaseSchema` and just change the value in your derived schema

You can check the docs for extending schema and reduce code redundancy here https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#custom-class-meta-options

Comment: Hi! It's better to post some example code with explanations than just pasting a url.